# Convert JSON to SQL and insert data in DB2 using NiFi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I need to generate SQL insert statement using JSON data (key-value pairs) and execute the INSERT SQL statement to write to DB2. I am using processors ConvertJSONtoSQL and PutSQL in NiFi. My PutSQL is throwing error.

PutSQL Configuration:

[image]

I am getting output flow file like this.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Are the question marks expected? I am getting error in the PutSQL processor.

[image]

Comment: what does your json look like and what is the table schema?

Comment: I figured this. It was due to date mismatch fields. I had to do a date conversion using Update Processor. Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it. @Sdairs

Answer (score 1):

The question marks are expected as this is the way JSON to SQL processor works.
I think this is data error where data type is not matching with SQL table column data types. Please revalidate your data.